# Jasmine react component test failing

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Try to setup testing using Karma and Jasmine.

Would like to setup gulp watch tasks - I have my gulp file with the following tasks:

```
gulp.task('default', ['browserify','css','karma'], function () {
    gulp.watch('../App/src/**/*.js', ['browserify']);
    gulp.watch('../App/src/**/*.css', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('../App/src/tests/**/*.js', ['rewireAndSetupTests']);
    gulp.watch('../App/src/tests/**/*.js', ['karma']);
});
```

All my tests are currently failing with the error:

```
[08:46:15] Starting Karma server...
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.37 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket  3xjo1pLi0mPkCJQlk9Cd with id 68708323
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module
  at d:/Source/tests/stub/channelStub.js:25
```

can anyone tell me how I can my tests setup?

Here is my karma config:

```
var webpack = require("webpack"),
path = require("path");

module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine"],
    files: [
        "node_modules/phantomjs-polyfill/bind-polyfill.js",
        "./App/src/tests/bundle.js"
    ],
    webpack: {
        module: {
            loaders: [
                { test: /\.js$/, loader: "jsx-loader" }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ResolverPlugin([
                new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
            ])
        ],
        resolve: {
            root: [path.join(__dirname, "./bower_components"), path.join(__dirname, "./src")]
        }
    },
    webpackMiddleware: {
        noInfo: true
    },
    plugins: [
        require("karma-webpack"),
        require("karma-jasmine"),
        require("rewire-webpack"),
        require("phantomjs"),
        require("karma-phantomjs-launcher"),
       require("karma-chrome-launcher")
    ],
    reporters: ["dots"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
    singleRun: false
});
};
```

**UPDATE:** seems to be a problem with vinyl-transform, does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
gulp.task('rewireAndSetupTests', function () {

var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
    console.log(filename);
    var b = browserify(filename);
    b.transform({ global: true }, reactify);
    b.transform({ global: true }, rewireify);
    return b;
});
return gulp.src(['./app/src/tests/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('suite.js'))
    .pipe(browserified)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));

});
```

Comment: If you are browserify-ing in the gulp task, why are you also using the webpack preprocessor?

Comment: Thanks I've removed that line of code. Still keep getting the error  Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined